# Boolean function expression

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra, binary, binary-operations, bit-strings

I have an interesting problem.

How do  I express the following as a boolean function?

> **HD** ($2^4$, 1100) >=2

**HD** = Hamming distance

$2^4$= {0000,0001,0010.....all 16 binary values}

The answer is {0001,0010,0011,0101,0110,0111,1001,1010,1011}

So I am trying to express all the binary bits that have HD >=2 with 1100 in *boolean function*.

Please let me know the proper notations for representation too e.g. what's the proper notation to represent all 16, 4 bits in binary?

Comment: "binary bits"? You mean bit-strings? $0000$ is a string of $4$ bits. And your $2^4$ is the set of those strings that have length $4$, or $\{0,1\}^4$ in some notations.

Comment: A Boolean function is the same as a subset?

Comment: Yes, bit strings. And no by boolean function I mean this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_function

Comment: Don’t you know an algorithm to write a truth table as a Boolean function? You know the table..

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I don't understand. Would you be able to write a truth table for the example given above?

Comment: You have 4 columns,  for the four bits $x_1,x_2, x_3, x_4$ and one that has $0$ when the distance is $< 2$ and $1$ for your strings that are distance $2$ or more. You can make that table, I think?

Comment: Its unclear to me what the argument $1100$ means? $1100_2 = 12_{10}$, so what is it representing

Comment: 1100 just means this beat string itself...I am comparing all 16 bit strings with this for calculation of HD.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Do you know of any algorithm that would be able to find all the elements in this set?

Answer (score 1):

I would write $\{0,1\}^4$ for the set of all bitstrings of length $4$, and the set you want as $$\{x \in \{0,1\}^4: d_H(x,0010) \ge 2\}$$ where I use $d_H$ for Hamming distance.

A Boolean function (in this context) is a *function* from $\{0,1\}^4$ to $\{0,1\}$ and is a different type of object.

Comment: Can you please explain your last line? What is {0,1}?

Comment: @zaki the set consting of $0$ and $1$.

Comment: There is no set with {0,1} here ...all are 4 bits so it's like {0000, 0001, 0010,....}

Comment: @zaki a Boolean function has value $0$ or $1$.

Comment: oh right sorry ..now I get it.

Comment: Hi is there any way to use xor here? and also break the >= operator?

Comment: @zaki $d_H(x,0010)=\|x\oplus 0010\|$ where the norm is just the number of $1$’s in the vector. The $\ge$ is taken in $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Actually what I am asking is: Say for HD (2^4, 0000) >=2 the boolean expression is x1 (x2+x3+x4) + x2 (x3+x4) + x3 (x4) for HD (2^4, 0000) >=3 the expression is x3 (x1x4+ x1x2+x2x4). If I vary n and p in HD (2^n, 0000) >=p is there any general way to express this in boolean expression in terms of xor or any other operator?